# Creating stable 72V power source

Tags: power-supply, led-driver, ws2812b

For a lighting project, I want to power 12 programmable LEDS (WS2812b or equivalent) in series, and then have 5 of these sets in parallel. Due to extra resistance, I think I need a constant voltage source of 72V*. Dedicated 72V sources are surprisingly expensive, and as I need only some 300 mA I figured I should be able to convert from e.g. a 36V power source. I found many ways to do this, but I don't know which one will be stable enough for these kind of LEDs. I couldn't find any articles that go into enough detail to answer this without being full-fledged electronics books that are a bit too hard for me to follow.

- Is my assumption correct that I should get a constant voltage source? I suspect a constant current source would mess with the integrated circuits, is that correct?
- What would be the best way to achieve the 72V?

  - Chaining two 36V supplies? Straight forward, but is this stable enough, and how should I connect the grounds?
  - Voltage doubling circuit? Has simple components, but is it stable enough?
  - DC-to-DC converter? So many [versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter) that I don't know which one is best.
  - Dedicated 230V AC -> 72V DC supply, more expensive option, but straight forward.

Thanks for helping out!

---

* *For artistic purposes, the power will actually be delivered through pencils instead of wires, which have a resistance on the order of 10 ohms each. I experimented with this with non-programmable LEDs and there it works fine.*

---

EDIT: a schematic as suggested in the comments; this is what I'd like to set up, but then with 5 strings of 12 instead of two strings of 3.

[image: schematic of the project, with two strings of 3 where I'd like to use 5 strings of 12 LEDs]

As I'd like to make a snub dodecahedron:

[image: Snub dodecahedron]

with LEDs on the vertices and pencils as the edges, with some providing power and others providing data. Connection-wise, this is possible by injecting power and data at the 5 vertices of one of the pentagon faces and having the LEDs powered as 5 times a series of 12; there are not enough vertices to provide power to all LEDs in parallel without injecting power at more points, which will make it less pretty.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a block diagram or schematic. This may be an XY issue. I would wire two isolated 36 V supplies in series, with a bypass diode across each, or six 12 V supplies.

Comment: You can't connect the power in series if you expect to pass programming data from LED to LED in the usual way. For that to work, the LEDs must share a common ground.

Comment: Actually, the self-clocking data signal is (mostly) AC, so I don't see any reason it couldn't be AC coupled. Use a 1 nF capacitor between DOUT and DIN of the next chip, and connect a 100k resistor between DIN and VSS of the same chip. Connect a Shottky doide in parallel with the resistor for DC restoration. Has anyone ever tried anything like this?

Comment: Those "LEDs" aren't merely LEDs.  They are a combined serial bus controller, constant current source, PWM controller, and three LEDs.  I think if you stack them in series, it will end the same way stacking electric motors in series does - smoke and tears.  The WS2812b is intended to be operated with the power lines in parallel and with the data lines passed through each chip.

Comment: As others note - these devices are made to be chained so supply voltages are in parallel and data line is daisychained.  You MIGHT be able to series connect the power supplies (MIGHT) but the data feed would at best not work and quite possibly destroy stuff - see data sheets and application note links. | You need a single 5V supply. ALL devices are in parallel supply wise. Then daisy chain the data lines in substrings as desired.

Comment: 60 LEDs at 50mA maximum each (from the datasheet) is 3A.

Comment: @JRE: I agree with the 3A, but that's only if I stack them in series, right? Which would unfortunately screw up my initial idea.

Comment: That's 3A if you connect the power to the LEDs in *parallel* as they are intended to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others note - these devices are made to be chained so supply voltages are in parallel and data lines are daisychained.

You MIGHT be able to series connect the power supplies (MIGHT) but the data feed would at best not work and quite possibly this would 'destroy stuff'
See data sheets and application note links below for correct operation.

You need a single 5V supply.
ALL devices are in parallel supply wise.
Then daisy chain the data lines in substrings as desired.
eg all 60 powered by 5V, in 5 strings of 12, with 5 data feeds.

[WS2812 datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/WS2812.pdf) & [here](https://resources.kitronik.co.uk/pdf/WS2812B-LED-datasheet.pdf)

[Sparkfun hookup guide](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Sparkfun%20PDFs/WS2812_Breakout_Hookup_Guide.pdf)

[How To Control WS2812B Individually Addressable LEDs](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-control-ws2812b-individually-addressable-leds-using-arduino/)

**_________________________**

> I know that parallel power is the conventional way of setting this up, but I cannot find anywhere in the links why series power will not work.

There is nowhere in the links that says series power WILL work.
And if you just connect them it will not work.
(Data sheets and application notes generally focus on what you should do and/or 
 can do.
They tend not to mention what you can't do, or what you really really shouldn't do.
They often have "absolute maximum" ratings. Connecting the LEDs in series directly very substantially exceeds some of the absolute maximum ratings. This is liable to be a very very bad idea :-).

The Din and Dout leads are reference to ground (5V -ve) for the related IC.
If you series the power feeds then then if say LED1 is at 0/5V, then
LED 2 is at 5/10V,
LED3 is at 10/15V ... then

LED1_Dout swings 0-5V,
LED2 expects to see 5V-10V on Din
so the Dout from LED 1 is 0/-5V relative to LED2 ground.
This will not work and may destroy either or both LEDs.

If you chain them the other way with Vout descending then
LED2-Din sees +10/+5 which also will not work and may destroy one or both LEDs.

While you could TRY to level shift the voltages up or down in each of these cases, it may not work and may still cause magic smoke.

ALSO series connecting the power supplies if the devices draw differing currents (as they will at various times) will with a supply of N x 5V, result in more than 5V across the low current devices.
You could eg place a 4V7 zener across each LED supply - and it MAY work, but you are building a super non standard arrangement for no apparently good reason.

I could make this work if I had to (after 50+ years of playing a small amount of magic ability is granted) but I'd not consider trying unless there was an utterly utterly compelling reason to do so.
I can't see that there is

Comment: Thanks for the useful links! I know that parallel power is the conventional way of setting this up, but I cannot find anywhere in the links why series power will not work. Could you maybe explain what goes wrong exactly, such that I do not make similar mistakes in the future?

Comment: @JanB The Din and Dout leads are reference to ground (5V -ve) for the related IC. If you series the power feeds then then if say LED1 is at 0/%V, LED 2 is at 5/10V, LED3 is at 10/15V ... then - LEd1_Dout swings 0-5V, LED2 expects to see 5V-10V on Din so the Dout from LED 1 is 0/-5V relative to LED2 ground. This will not work and may desctroy either or both LEDs. If you chain them the other way with Vout descending then LED2-Din sees +10/+5 which also will not work and may desroyt one of both LEDs. While you could TRY to level shift the voltages up or down in each of these cases, it may not ...

Comment: work and may still cause magic smoke. || ALSO seriesing the power supplies if the devices draw differing currents (as they will at various times) will with a supply of N x 5V, 5V across the low current devices. You could eg place a 4V7 zxenera cross each LED supply - and it MAY work, but you are building a super non standard arrangement for no apparently good reason. || I could make this work if I had to (after 50+ years of playing a small amount of magic ability is granted) but I'd not consider trying unless there was an utterly utterly compelling reason to do so. I can't see that there is.

Comment: Thanks, that's super clear! Accepting your answer.